# datetime compare time python

Tags: python, datetime

I have 2 events A and B. I have already created a function get_schedule(event) to get the date and time of A and B occurring in datetime.
For example:

```
    get_schedule(a) -> datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 2, 25)
```

How can I create a function to check if my event occurs before/after a certain timing irregardless of the date? I thought about slicing the time and comparing but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: I don't use Python, so I can't answer your question. But I am quite sure that Python provides functions to extract the time from a datetime and to compare times, and I am convinced that the documentation shows how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can get *just* the time object by calling the [`datetime.time()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time). Compare that to another `time` object:

```
# scheduled after 12 noon.
get_schedule(a).time() > datetime.time(12, 0)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 2, 25).time()
datetime.time(2, 25)
>>> datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 2, 25).time() > datetime.time(12, 0)
False
```